# Azure DevOps 2020 OnPrem - Trigger Action On Work Item create

Tags: azure-devops, webhooks, azure-boards

I am working with Azure DevOps 2020 RTW (ADO) OnPrem i would like to trigger an action when work-item (WIT) is created
Flow:

1. Create a WIT on web portal
2. On WIT creation trigger the creation of several work item - based on fields values from first WIT

I understand i need to use webhooks - i couldn't find any guide
please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some testing the fast way is to set an Azure Function OnPrem
and use the web hooks with the event `Work item created` to trigger the Function and create the work items.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid your requirement is not able to be achieved with webhooks by default. The [service hooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/overview?view=azure-devops) in azure devops is that when something(event) happens in Azure Devops it runs task(action) on target service. For [Web Hooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/services/webhooks?view=azure-devops), it can't trigger actions that create several work item - based on fields values from first WIT when create a work item. It just sends the Json representation.

You can consider using [Azure Devops Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to trigger actions (create several work item - based on fields values from first WIT) once you get successful status from web hooks

Comment: Can the folllowing be achieved:
1) use webhook to trigger specific build - which include a script to achive step 2 (or use YAML)
2) Build will run a RestAPI and create several Workitems

Comment: Webhooks provide a way to send a JSON representation of an event to any service. It can not trigger specific build. Opposite, a build completed event can trigger a web hook.

Comment: any idea how to accomplish this on the event of workitem creation ???

Comment: There is no default way. You can try to create a custom service to receive the JSON representation of `Work item created` event, and then use Azure Devops Rest API to create other work items after receiving the JSON representation.